# Golang GORM: how to select multiply models from single query with Preaload

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have a set of models and I want to get them in one request, but I get a mapping error: `Result's field Model1: define a valid foreign key for relations or implement the Valuer/Scanner interface.`

```golang
type Result struct {
    Model1     models.Model1
    Model2     models.Model2
}

var result []Result

query := repo.DB.Table("model1").
    Select("model1.*, model2.*").
    Preload("Account").
    Joins("model2")

if err := query.Find(&result).Error; err != nil {
    return nil, err // Error: Result's field Model1: define a valid foreign key for relations or implement the Valuer/Scanner interface.
}
```

I tried to do the mapping manually, it works, but Preload doesn't work - access by `Model1.Account` doesn't work.

```golang
rows, err := query.Rows()
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
defer rows.Close()

for rows.Next() {
    var model1 models.Model1
    var model2 models.Model2
    if err := repo.DB.ScanRows(rows, &model1); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    if err := repo.DB.ScanRows(rows, &model2); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    result = append(result, Result{Model1: model1, Model2: model2})
}
```

```golang
fmt.PrintLn(result[0].Model1.Account) // does not work, Account is empty
```